# NextJS Query Params are Empty and using isReady

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I'm new to NextJS and I have a question. Is there any way to get query params when not using SSR? I'm trying to access params from the following:

This is the URL:
https://localhost:3000/test?querytest=Test

```
export default function Test (){
const router = useRouter();

console.log(router)
return();
}
```

But I am returned a empty object for the query part of router: {}.  Doing some research I saw this thread: https://github.com/vercel/next.js/pull/9370

But I don't really understand what its saying to do. Thanks for any help!!

Answer (score 0):

I have reproduced your example, it's working fine and the `router.query` is not null

```
export default function Test() {
  const router = useRouter();
  const { querytest } = router.query;

  console.log(router);
  return <div>{querytest}</div>;
}
```